# Setting up MySQL server in local machine

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've created a MySQL server in my local machine with default settings. Now I'm trying to connect to that Database with Oracle Sql Developers with

```
Connection Name: mySQLDB
Username: root
Password: ******

Connection Type: Basic
Hostname: localhost
Port: 3306
SID:____
```

I'm not sure what the SID would be, by default its `xe`., I've tried using this it won't work.

Here is the error my getting.

```
Status : Failure-Test failed: String index out of range: 14137
```

Could someone please help me out in connecting to the database in MySQL servers.

Comment: Oracle SQL is not MySQL - though to confuse the issue MySQL is owned by Oracle now. I doubt the products are compatible. If you want an interface to the database, MySQL Workbench works quite well

Comment: That's Very silly but that really worked :)
thanks @josh.trow.